# Convert from LyX/Latex to wordpress post

Tags: lyx, html

I have some documents in LyX/Latex and I want them as a wordpress post. I have tried converting latex to HTML (with latex2html) and afterwards, pasting that code in the wordpress editor but everything looks ugly. Do you know a better approach?

Comment: You may be interested in [this project](http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML)

Comment: do you mean I can convert to XML and then paste in wordpress? I have already converted from LyX to XML and then pasted in wordpress, but results look awkward

Comment: Wordpress has a a very good QuickLaTeX plugin for math expressions, however, it's not so sophisticated for other macros.

Comment: well, i Just tried a very basic document (my CV) and could not import it correctly

Comment: Can you tell us what looks wrong, or provide a screenshot? Without more detail on what the problem is and a minimum working example, we can't even begin to guess what might be wrong on the LaTeX side.

Answer (score 3):

That's an old question, but I have stumbled upon it recently and thought that it might help pointing out to the link below

https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/converting-latex-to-wordpress/

Seems like someone came-up with an automatic script in python that can translate math oriented latex to nice wordpress formatted text.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress supports a couple different formatting options, including HTML and Markdown. You can convert LaTeX to either of these formats, as well as several others, using [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). But it's probably not the low-level formatting that you are objecting to, but things like margins, header positions, colors, choice of font, and other elements that simply don't get translated, because they are dependent on the intended final form. LaTeX document class, `\usepackage`, and the like don't get translated to HTML, and on the HTML side, anything controlled by CSS generally won't get translated into LaTeX.

Wordpress has themes available that control the way the website looks, and the style of individual elements like headings are going to be controlled by adding a CSS class to the element, something like `<P CLASS="myparagraphstyle">`. You should really talk to other Wordpress users about this, since it probably has nothing to do with LaTeX.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I am desperate, do not know what to do!